# Upload list of files with RequestParams

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I'm trying to upload more than one file using `RequestParams` in Android. The issue is that `put()` method overwrite the value when using the same key, which means that at the end will send only one `File`.

And I've tried to send the `ArrayList` directly. That didn't work either. Isn't there a way to send all the files directly to the server?? It's not login if I have 10 pictures, I have to call my API 10 times!

Here's how I'm receiving the list on my server (Written in .NET Core):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm] IList<IFormFile> files)
{
}
```

And here's how I'm sending the files in Android:

```
List<File> uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
for (String path : images) {
    File uploadedFile = new File(path);
    uploadedFiles.add(uploadedFile);
}
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("files", uploadedFiles);
HttpHelper.UploadAttachment("Attachments", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        String uploadedUrls = new String(responseBody);
        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Upload was successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is only one put() call in your code. So how can it overwrite something?

Comment: `adding file to params using for loop` There is no for loop in your code that adds to params.

Comment: I meant that when I used the for loop, it overwrite the previous values and sent only 1 file to the server. So putting the array directly in `put` or using for loop with the same key didn't work

Comment: I see only one for loop and it adds items to a list. I bed that the list contains several items so where are you talking about?

Comment: Yes here `uploadedFiles` is an array of files. Which isn't received at the server side. I'm saying if I add `params.put()` to the for loop, and then post with the `params` value it will only send one file. I will need to put the post request inside the for loop to send all files, which is not logical because if I have 10 pictures, then I will send 10 Post requests

Comment: You have talked about too much scenarios. Please edit your post so it is clear what you want. And post complete code for one scenario.

Comment: `params.put("files", uploadedFiles);` That looks ok. A list with many files. Are you saying that only the last file of the list is uploaded? Pretty strange.

Comment: Okay I've edited the question, forget about the for loop mentioned before. If my code is now like this, what's wrong with sending list of files?

Comment: I dont know. Is HttpHelper.UploadAttachment() expecting such a list with File objects? Look in the source. And there should be example code on the internet.